# nginx server blocks some ip address

Tags: centos, nginx

I realize that the nginx server block some IP but don't know how to troubleshoot this .

Here is the current state :

- From machine A I can access to foo.com (foo.com is under nginx)
- From machine B (different ip ) I can't access to foo.com but I can ping it's ip address

I've searched under the nginx.conf but I didn't found any deny rule

Comment: dns on machine b? nslookup foo.com what ip does it return.

Comment: I get get the ip with ns lookup and I can ping this adress from A

Comment: okay. You do not need to paste the IP :). If you can access the site from machine b, but only with the "ip address". This is a DNS issue with machine b.

Comment: if it's a DNS issue How to troubleshoot this ? , machine B is an ordinary computer

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Nginx access logs for the source IP address, the log defaults to something like:

```
/var/log/nginx_access.log
```

It can also be defined in the configuration file using the `access_log` directive as documented [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLogModule#access_log).

It's probably also worth checking iptables to make sure you have no rules that are inadvertently blocking these connections.

Comment: for iptables , as I mention I can ping the ip address from all the machines